# Gwt Material Design - MaterialNavBrand text responsible

Tags: gwt, gwt-material-design

I'm programming a GWT application, where I need to show in header a title with five words, for example: "Academia de Baile Nuria Villamuelas". 
(Well, I would like to add a Header with a SubHeader, but I haven't found how to do that with GWT Material Design).
I don't know what I'm doing wrong but when I test with different screens size, the text is truncated.

I would like to have the following behavior:

[image]

But I have this:

[image]

The code of my testings is:

```
<m:MaterialHeader>
            <m:MaterialNavBar activates="sidenav">
                <m:MaterialNavBrand layoutPosition="FIXED" text="Academia de baile Nuria Villamuelas"
                                    centerOn="CENTER_ON_SMALL"
                                    textColor="INDIGO_DARKEN_4"/>
                <m:MaterialNavSection float="RIGHT">
                    <m:MaterialLink text="Link 1"/>
                    <m:MaterialLink iconType="POLYMER"/>
                </m:MaterialNavSection>
            </m:MaterialNavBar>
        </m:MaterialHeader>
```

Thank you.
Nuria